# Google Map marker disappears after drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps-api-3

When I move a marker to top of my map and out of view (see image below), it gets a high opacity which makes the marker close to invisible.

This bug only happens in Safari and I really have no clue what might be causing this.

[image: Image showing marker while doing move]

[image: Image showing marker after move ended with opacity bug]

If you look close at the second image you can see the marker.

```
    var myMarker = new Array();

$(function () {

    latitude = 59.3294;
    longitude = 18.0686;


    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
        zoom: 4,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
        }
    }

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);

        var id = 1;

        var image = {
        url: 'http://i.imgur.com/4yjea7s.png',
        // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
        size: new google.maps.Size(33, 42),
        // The origin for this image is 0,0.
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 42)
    };
            myMarker[id] = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(57.721035,12.939819),
                map: map,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                draggable: false,
                icon: image
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker[id], 'click', function() {
           var image = {
        url: 'http://i.imgur.com/1eHR1c3.png',
        // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
        size: new google.maps.Size(108, 141),
        // The origin for this image is 0,0.
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(54, 0)
      };
      myMarker[id].setDraggable(true);
      myMarker[id].setIcon(image);
          });

    });
```

**jsfiddle**: 
http://jsfiddle.net/S5T9b/1/

http://jsfiddle.net/S5T9b/1/embedded/result/

Steps to reproduce the error:

1. Click on a marker on the map
2. Drag the marker to the far top of the map div and drop it.

The marker should now be almost invisible but if you look closely it's still there.
And you can still click on it again and move it - It then becomes visible again.

Is it a programming issue by me or is this a google maps bug in Safari?

Comment: jsfiddle is not showing marker for your code?

Comment: What do you mean?

Can't you see the markers on the map? They are visible for me.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure this is a Google maps bug. However I got it to work by using this solution:

You have to both specify a `zIndex` and add

```
optimized: false
```

to **every** marker constructor, eg.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: markerLatLng,
    map: map,
    icon: resultIcon,
    optimized: false,
    zIndex: 5
})
```

Copied from :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12061606/1679809

Comment: optimized:false made it, w/o using zIndex. We are using an opacity on the map, which may have caused the (confirmed) Google maps bug.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me in Safari using Windows 7. It is possible that this is just a tiny bug, since from your code I can't see anything that would cause the code to work fine on all browsers except Safari.

I'm not sure if these guys have the exact same problem as you, but it might be worth checking the links out anyway:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/maps/thread?tid=56c196bd9ad37c24&hl=en

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/maps/thread?tid=26db8fd040386548&hl=en

[Why are Google Map markers showing up on Firefox by not on Chrome, Safari and Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088997/why-are-google-map-markers-showing-up-on-firefox-by-not-on-chrome-safari-and-in)

Comment: It was in Safari that after moving the marker to the top it would get some wierd opacity issue. It turns out it was a z-index bug. So if I dont define zIndex when I create the marker it will be invisible in Safari. I think this is a google maps bug actually.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/12061606/1679809